# multiple addOrderBy in doctrine/symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I wanted to order the item pictures that I have in my database based on the shop priority that has the highest priority first, then number of likes, and the created date:

So I have the following:

```
 $picturesQuery = $qb->select('DISTINCT p')
                    ->from("AppMainBundle:Picture", 'p')
                    ->innerJoin('p.shop', 'shop')
                    ->addOrderBy('shop.priority', 'DESC')
                    ->addOrderBy('p.numberoflikes', 'DESC')
                    ->addOrderBy('p.created', 'DESC')
                              ;
```

However it doesn't work. I have a shop which has the highest priority, but the item from that shop isn't showing on the top of the query results. Is it okay to have multiple order by? How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: It should work... what's the actual resulting query?

Answer (score 0):

You need to *fetch join* `shop` Something like this (untested).

```
$picturesQuery = $qb->select('DISTINCT p', 'shop')
```

[Reference](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/ordered-associations.html)

Comment: this doesnt make any sense, why am I also selecting the shop?

Comment: @adit I'm assuming because Doctrine is lazy. Have you tried it? I'll happily remove my answer if it does not work. :)